# function Mysql-connect Error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem on connection.php file, the file runs fine when on localhost, but when upload to hosting an error like this:

```
Warning: mysql_connect () [function.mysql-connect]: Can not connect to local MySQL server through socket '/ var / lib / mysql / mysql.sock' (2) in / home/content/84/10207284/html / koneksi.php on line 6
```

My script like this:

```
<? php
    $server = "localhost";
    $username = "*******";
    $password = "******";
    $database = "*****";
    mysql_connect ("$server", "$username", "$password") or die ("Failed");/ /  the error Line
    mysql_select_db ("holidayhappy") or die ("Database not found");
?>
```

I have tried to change localhost with Server IP ann port, but it is not working too.

Can Someone Help me to Fix this Problem...?

Comment: Have you checked whether MySQL is running? If not try running this command on the command line '/etc/init.d/mysql status'

Comment: @Ifthikhan Is running normally on localhost, Now I will try in server hosting. I have upload n Import my database successfully. The problem is cannot connect.

Comment: @Uchsun So it's a server problem not a code problem. Tell this problem to your server admin.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using server hosting, and mysql server is installed on same host

then try servername as localhost

if not then make sure remote access is enabled

Following the tutorial in below mentioned link

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html